# Extracting phonetic pronunciation from a crawler returns a blank []

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract phonetic alphabet from a Spanish-English dictionary.

[SpanishDict.com](https://www.spanishdict.com/)

For example, when búsqueda is searched, its phonetic alphabet will be (boos-keh-dah).

[definition of búsqueda](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/b%C3%BAsqueda)

But after I run the .py, it only shows me [] as a result.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Here's the code I wrote:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/"

search_keyword = input("input the keyword : ")

url = base_url + search_keyword + "&start="

spanishdict_r = requests.get(url)

spanishdict_soup = BeautifulSoup(spanishdict_r.text, 'html.parser')

print(spanishdict_soup.findAll('dictionaryLink--369db'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, remove `"&start="`. It doesn't load desired results. So URL should be `url = base_url + search_keyword`.

Second, the translation is present in `<span class="dictionaryLink--369db">`, which is a `span` tag with `class` value `dictionaryLink--369db`.
Therefore, your search should be `spanishdict_soup.find('span', {'class': 'dictionaryLink--369db'})`.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/"
search_keyword = 'búsqueda'
url = base_url + search_keyword
spanishdict_r = requests.get(url)
spanishdict_soup = BeautifulSoup(spanishdict_r.text, 'html.parser')
print(spanishdict_soup.find('span', {'class': 'dictionaryLink--369db'}).text)
```

Output:

```
(boos-keh-dah)
```